# Pattern Recognition on Images

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision, image-recognition

I need to develop an application where I will have to match images for similarity.

- Mostly these images will be of animals, and I need to match same animal if its already there in the DB.

What image processing libraries can I use to develop this? is there an opensource framework available to accomplish this?

At this point I am open to any language but Java would be preferable.

Thanks in advance!
AJ

Comment: This is potentially an insanely hard problem. Could you post samples of images you intend to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/), the Java interface to OpenCV and a lot of other computer vision libraries is what you are looking for. [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) contains most of the basic computer vision building blocks you'd need for such a project.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/index.html) is often recommended in answers to similar questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

On http://www.vlfeat.org/ you can find some popular, open source computer vision algorithms including HOG, SIFT, k-means, hierarchical k-means etc., while on http://koen.me/research/colordescriptors/ the binaries to compute color descriptors within an image, such as color histograms and color SIFT descriptor are provided.

Furthermore, in  [MediaMixer Deliverable D1.1.2](http://www.mediamixer.eu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/D1.1.2-final_Update1.pdf) you can find useful information about the implementation of image descriptors on concept detection and image classification. For further information you can join the MediaMixer community portal on http://community.mediamixer.eu/.